# Cluster a signal to minimise variance of each cluster with constraints on cluster size

Tags: clustering

Assume there is an incoming signal which may have some noise to it. This is essentially an ordered 1d data. I am looking for an algorithm which can group the data points into groups with minimum variance, given constraints on the number of elements for each group (for example each group/cluster needs to have at least 20 and at most 50 data points). If at the end less than MIN_SIZE points are left unclustered it is fine, as the cluster they belong they may yet be received. The number of groups/clusters is unknown before running the algorithm. Is there a suitable algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Does the clustering need to be performed as the data come in, with no opportunities to change the assignments later?

Comment: it can be redone on each new data point (or a batch of them)

Comment: You could perform unconstrained clustering first (say, k-means). Then reassign some points to other clusters to make n in clusters as you wish. Assign a point which is peripheral in its own cluster to some another cluster seeking more points to include and which is next close to our point. Silhouette clustering criterion is what can provide you the necessary quantities. Silhouette exists in several versions, including the Deviation aka "Simplified" type which is related to the idea of minimizing variance.